# Update Clock and Text in UI PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a problem to put the actual time while the UI is running, also the text y would like to change it in a certain period of time. I also try to use MainWindow.update() in my case Reloj.update() but it continue with the same problem, put it with an loop it's a bad idea.

I will put some code just to see how is working

The Ui is made by QtDesigner and then export to python.
My problem is that I have an UI that it shows all but it doesn't update the clock and the text.
I want to put the actual time while the UI is running.
Also the text is going to change in a certain period of time. I want to change the text after 15 minutes, but in this case I put a "delay" of 15 seconds, And the Ui doesn't change.

Also i try to update the Ui using Reloj.update(), but it doesn't change too.

Here is the example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class Ui_Reloj(object):
    def setupUi(self, Reloj):
        Reloj.setObjectName("Reloj")
        Reloj.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Reloj)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Texto = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.Texto.setObjectName("Texto")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Texto, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Reloj_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralWidget)
        self.Reloj_2.setObjectName("Reloj_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Reloj_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        Reloj.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Reloj)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 20))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        Reloj.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(Reloj)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        Reloj.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Reloj)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        Reloj.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(Reloj)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Reloj)

        """ Reloj """
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        texto_reloj = time.toString('HH:mm')
        if (time.second() % 2) == 0:
                texto_reloj = texto_reloj[:2] + ' ' + texto_reloj[3:]

        self.Reloj_2.display(texto_reloj)

        """ Texto que Cambia """
        vec = ['Hola','Que Tal?', 'No se toca', 'paradise']
        self.cambiar_texto(vec)

    def retranslateUi(self, Reloj):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Reloj.setWindowTitle(_translate("Reloj", "Reloj"))
        self.Texto.setText(_translate("Reloj", "Texto que cambia"))

    def showTime(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('HH:mm')
        if (time.second() % 2) == 0:
            text = text[:2] + ' ' + text[3:]
        self.Reloj_2.display(text)

    """ Cambiar Texto cada X tiempo (ejemplo 15 Minutos) """
    def cambiar_texto (self,vec):
        i=0
        length_string = len(vec)
        time.sleep(15)
        self.Texto.setText(vec[i])
        if (i == 3):
            i=0
        else:
            i+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Reloj = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Reloj()
    ui.setupUi(Reloj)
    Reloj.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There is no errors while it's compiling, but it should update the clock and the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use time.sleep() in the main GUI thread as it blocks the event loop, instead use QTimer. On the other hand do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer but create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

```py
from itertools import cycle

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Reloj(object):
    def setupUi(self, Reloj):
        Reloj.setObjectName("Reloj")
        Reloj.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Reloj)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Texto = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.Texto.setObjectName("Texto")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Texto, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Reloj_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralWidget)
        self.Reloj_2.setObjectName("Reloj_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Reloj_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        Reloj.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Reloj)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 20))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        Reloj.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(Reloj)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        Reloj.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Reloj)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        Reloj.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(Reloj)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Reloj)

    def retranslateUi(self, Reloj):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Reloj.setWindowTitle(_translate("Reloj", "Reloj"))
        self.Texto.setText(_translate("Reloj", "Texto que cambia"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Reloj):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        timer1 = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000, timeout=self.showTime)
        timer1.start()
        self.showTime()

        vec = ["Hola", "Que Tal?", "No se toca", "paradise"]
        self.texts = cycle(vec)
        timer2 = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=15 * 1000, timeout=self.cambiar_texto)
        timer2.start()
        self.cambiar_texto()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def showTime(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString("HH mm" if time.second() % 2 == 0 else "HH:mm")
        self.Reloj_2.display(text)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def cambiar_texto(self):
        text = next(self.texts)
        self.Texto.setText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```